# How can i convert 2d array into matrix in C?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

i have a 2d array(see the attached photo) which is for an image.
How can i convert this into a matrix using the ASCII "!@#$%^&*".( it has to be shown like those here http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/asciiart/ .

the programming language is C.
thanks

[here is the 2d array that i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eqe3.png)

the code that wrote was :

```
    #include <stdio.h>



    int LenaFace[300][300];
    int counter0 =0;
 


int main(){
 

    for(int WholeArrayLengte = 0; WholeArrayLengte< 512; WholeArrayLengte++){
        for(int WholeArrayBreedte = 0; WholeArrayBreedte < 512; WholeArrayBreedte++){
            counter0=counter0+lena[WholeArrayLengte][WholeArrayBreedte];
        }
    }
    printf("the average gracyscale value is:  %d\n" , counter0/(512*512));


   

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'matrix'? C has no built-in concept of a matrix type. Also what do you mean by "ASCII matrix".

Comment: i need to change the numbers which are in the 2d Array(see the photo i added to the question) to ASCII symbols. 
the image should look like the matrix here " http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/asciiart/ "

Comment: It looks as if you don't understand the problem yourself. State what should happen with value 0, with value 100, with value 200. How would you use the ASCII sequence you provided? Why that sequence? In the reference page about ASCII art you linked there is an effective ramp of character density, which your list doesn't show.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] with what you tried.

Comment: Well, you have a code. Does it work? Probably, not, because things like `level[@]` would never compiled. Do you want us to help you in fixing those things? Or what? A "question post" implies a **question** statement, but I see no questions stated about your code...

Comment: now my code works( i changed the code in the post) but i believe that the header file is also needed.
my question was about how to write such a code to print the matrix of a photo which is given in the form of a 2d array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2-Dimensional array is basically matrix, so the question "I need to convert this 2d array into a matrix" is answered.

As for question "using the ASCII "!@#$%^&*"" you mean print it to console **you can use this basic code to print this "ASCII Art" to console:**

```cpp
int points[512][512] = {...};
// prints each row/col
for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
        printf("%c", points[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i need to change the numbers which are in the 2d Array(see the photo i added to the question) to ASCII symbols. the image needs to look like the matrix here "  http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/asciiart/" .

Comment: check the modified answer.

Comment: Any particular reason for changing OP's `char repr[512][512] ;` to `int points[512][512]`?

Comment: the previous code OP provided had int array, and variable name "repr" wasn't clear enough.